# Why would webpack dump a whole library in my bundle?

Tags: webpack

UPDATE: I no longer require a solution to this problem, yet think I should keep the question open in case anyone has the same issue, but don't think that my resolution deserves to be made into a stand-alone answer.

The cause is either [node-html-parser](https://github.com/taoqf/node-html-parser) or its dependency [he](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) doing something very odd (or perhaps not expecting to be used by a babel plugin) but due to other issues with node-html-parser I have decided to drop it in favour of an equivalent.

I'll still accept an answer which explains *why* this might have happened as that is technically the question being asked. I was using version 1.2.20 of node-html-parser (and could not update due to a breaking API change in 1.2.21).

---

Webpack seems to have dumped very strange code into my bundle, sending the size through the roof.

I can't paste actual code due to line wrapping, so here is a screenshot of the production output to give you an idea of what's been dumped in there:

[image: production]

It seems like it has something to do with https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he

Here is roughly the same spot in development mode in case that's more informative:

[image: development]

Here is a shortened webpack config which still causes it:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports =  function(env, argv) {
  return {
    entry: {
      'pages/collection/main': './src/pages/collection/main.js'
    }, 
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, `dist`),
      publicPath: "/static/"
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                plugins: [
                  'babel-plugin-redrunner',
                  '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
                ],
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I rolled back `babel-plugin-redrunner` to a version which I know didn't cause this.

I'm wondering if I perhaps have funky characters in my html strings in my ES6 code, or something silly like that...

Has anyone seen the likes of this before?

Comment: Can you show the config?

Comment: @SethLutske added it now, but like I said, config hasn't changed between now and a point when this didn't happen.

Comment: If that's the case the what are you importing in your code?  Perhaps check your `package-lock.json` for 'mathias' or 'he'...its gotta be coming from somewhere.

Comment: The author of that lib wrote half of npm so I thought it might be something very generic, but a bit of grepping shows it is a dependency of https://github.com/taoqf/node-html-parser, which actually broke my framework last week by introducing a massive breaking change in a patch version, so time to find a replacement for that :-)